# Lag Baomer - why not Laomer?

Tags: minhag, words, calendar, sefirat-ha-omer, lag-ba-omer

Nusach Askenaz says Baomer, Nusach Sefard and Sefardim say Laomer - Why does everyone call it Lag Baomer - why not call it Lag Laomer?

Comment: The Lag b'Omer as a day is called like any other day; Tu b'Shvat, Tisha b'Av. The nusach of the counting is not (necessarily) referring to the day, rather some count up to the Omer offering (and there is a disagreement how to refer to that). So I'm not sure I understand your question -- when you say "it" you mean the day or something else?

Comment: There is a legitimate answer to this question. When I say "it" i mean the day. The fact is that many people count Laomer yet they still call the day Lag Baomer - why? By Tisha B'Av and Tu B'Shevat there is no counting with a prefix like by the counting of Sefira.

Comment: Well if that is what you are asking, I thought my comment answered it -- lag b'omer in the counting that we perform at night is not a counting of a date (on the calendar, in which b' is used) rather it is a counting of a day (in a sequence of days), for which there is a disagreement (b' or l'). But I don't see any reason to think that how we count the days of the omer should have any bearing on how we refer to a calendar date.

Comment: @GershonGold There being a legitimate answer to the question doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: Minhag Ashkenaz is Lo'Omer, not Bo'Omer.

Answer (score 12):

In the Hagada Shel Pesach Gevuras Akiva he explains that the Rama is the one who holds that you should say Baomer, and Lag Baomer is the Yarzeit of the Rama. therefore in honor of the Rama everyone calls the day Lag Baomer.

Comment: Who authored that work? Does he cite a source for this explanation?

Comment: @DoubkeAA: The author is anonymous, and he does not cite a source.

Answer (score 10):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l [writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&pgnum=660) that there were halachic and kabbalistic reasons to switch from בעומר to לעומר in the counting (as discussed in the commentaries to Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 489:1). However, there was no real need to be so particular about dates and the like, so the older form was retained there. (This is similar to what Curiouser wrote in his comment, although slightly different: according to this approach, had the older version for counting indeed been היום יום אחד לעומר, etc., then we probably would indeed call it Lag Laomer. Indeed, I believe some Sephardim call it thus.)

In another letter, the Rebbe cites "sefarim of Polish [Rebbes]" - he doesn't specify which ones - who point out that ל"ג בעמר is equal in gematria to משה.

Comment: Moshe was also the name of the Rama whose Yarzeit is on Lag Baomer.

Comment: It's also the Gematria of השם and אל שדי.

Comment: That Gematria only works if you spell Omer without the vav, which is indeed how it is spelled in the Torah.

Comment: For the Polish sources see note 2 here http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/chasidim/otzar/9/15/49

Answer (score 4):

Many Sephardic rabbis and works (e.g. Yalkut Yosef) do indeed call it "Lag La'omer."